# What does equilibrium curve signify?

Tags: blood-circulation, respiration

While learning about gas exchange, I came across the haldane effect. Then i came across the CO2 -dissociation curve. Apparently the curves are "equilibrium curves". Does it mean that the curves were plotted when the system of blood was in equilibrium? Otherwise what does it signify?